# Effort EF6 alter app config connection strings for testing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, nunit, effort

My project has it's connection strings in the app.config. DBContexts are instantiated with `using (var myContext = new MyContext("name=MyContextConnectionString")) { ... }` and the operations are done inside the `using` scope.

How should I alter the config file during (test) runtime to make all of MyContext Instances use the same Effort Connection?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can alter directly `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCss"] = new ConnectStringSettings...`

Comment: @Vernou Something like that, yes, I'll try this. Thank you!